# Multivariate Taylor Series Expansion

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am struggling to find the Taylor series at (0,0) of the function:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1+y-yx^2-2x^2y^2}
\end{equation}

The first terms of the series are:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
    1 + (x^2 - 1) y + (x^4 + 1) y^2 + (x^2 - 1) (x^2 + 1)^2 y^3 + \\ \\
    + (x^8 + 2 x^6 - 2 x^4 + 2 x^2 + 1) y^4 + (x^{10} + 3 x^8 - 2 x^6 + 2 x^4 - 3 x^2 - 1) y^5 + O(y^6)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

so the resulting series should have the form:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x^2) y^n
\end{equation}

where $P_n(x^2)$ is a polynomial expression. I would like to know the general form of this polynomial.

Comment: You can do partial fraction decomposition. Factor the quadratic in $y$, in the denominator: $(y-r_1(x))(y-r_2(x))$. You would get two fractions $\frac{A(x)}{y-r_1(x)}+\frac{B(x)}{y-r_2(x)}$, which you can expand as $\frac{A(x)}{y-r_1(x)}=-\frac{A(x)}{r_1}\sum_n \frac{y^n}{r_1(x)^n}$. Then you need to expand each $\frac{A(x)}{r_1(x)^{n+1}}$ in series. You said that $P_n(x)$ are polynomials, but this doesn't need to be the case.

Comment: Seems not to be true that you can factor the denominator as $(y-r_1(x))(y-r_2(x))$

Comment: Of course [you can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). It is a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Sorry @flan I dont catch your idea. I think that if you expand $(y-r_1(x))(y-r_2(x))=y^2-(r_1(x)+r_2(x))y+r_1(x)r_2(x)$ but it does not replicate the poynomial. From one hand, there is no quadratic term in $y$, from the other the only way you can replicate the constat term is setting $r_1(x).r_2(x)=1$ which yields to be independent of x. Maybe I am not taking into account some details, can you be more explicit in the calculation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your denominator is $-2x^2y^2+(1-x^2)y+1$. This is equal to $$-\left(y-\frac{(1-x^2)+\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2+8x^2}}{4x^2}\right)\left(y-\frac{(1-x^2)-\sqrt{(1-x^2)^2+8x^2}}{4x^2}\right)$$

Comment: ok, the trick was that $r_1(x)$ and $r_2(x)$ were not polynomials. I will explore this path. Thanks!

Comment: Just like your $P_n$ don't have to be polynomials. The claim that they are is equivalent to the derivatives $\frac{\partial^m\partial^n}{\partial x^m\partial y^n}$ of your function are all zero for each $n$ and sufficiently large $m$. This doesn't have to be the case, and it probably isn't for your rational function.

Comment: I am quite sure that they are, and indeed it is equivalent to the condition you wrote in the last comment. I hope to upload the full answer as soon as possible. Really apreciate your contribution.